# Winform Set ComboBox Placeholder

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have the following ComboBox control populated as below

```
DataTable dt2 = InfoPCMS.db.executeSelectQuery("select * from Customer");

txtCustomer.DataSource = dt2;
txtCustomer.ValueMember = "Id";
txtCustomer.DisplayMember = "CustomerName";
```

How can I set a placeholder saying "Select a customer"

Comment: Generally, you use a label control, positioned either above or to the side of the combobox for this. What you describe is known as a "cue banner". There are lots of samples online. Which one you use depends on what *style* of combobox you have. Is it a DropDown or a DropDownList (i.e., user-editable or not user-editable)?

Comment: @CodyGray its a DropDownList and not user-editable

Answer (score 0):

This is no an answer to your question, but It will solve your problem. I think there is a better way to do the job, but this works:

```
DataTable dt2 = InfoPCMS.db.executeSelectQuery("select * from Customer");

foreach (DataRow row in dt2.Rows)
{
    ComboboxItem newItem = newComboboxItem(row["id"], row["CustomerName"]);
    txtCustomer.Items.Add(newItem);
}
txtCustomer.Items.Insert(0,"Select a customer");
txtCustomer.SelectedIndex = 0;

public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public ComboboxItem(object val, string txt)
    {
        this.Value = val;
         this.Text = txt;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's step one. Now how do you keep the user from selecting item 0, "Select a customer"?

Comment: I got "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set." error

Comment: check if the selected index is 0, and display an error message when it it. You can do it in the action trigger , a button for example.

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra, actually I don't use DataSource, I simply iterate on DataTable like this:
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    TextBox1.Text = row["ImagePath"].ToString();
}
convert it to your situation